# Select data from different SQL tables filtering by table name

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a lot of tables with the same columns and I need to extract data from all of them (like COUNT).

I know I can make a UNION statement, but I have 100 tables and all table names have the same format (example_table_1. example_table_2...). Is there a way to make a UNION of all the tables with a certain condition (in this case, table name contains "example_table")?

Thanks for your help, I'm a newbie in this.

Comment: What database are you using?

Comment: hi, what do you mean? I'm connecting to an MySQL Host

Comment: MySQL is the database then.  The answers to this question will vary by rdbms/database.

Comment: Why do you have 100 tables with the same columns? This is a [very poor design](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_normalization) and if possible, fixing this would be better than developing this query.

Comment: Hi, I have 100 tables because the database is really big and having only one huge table would cause the server to crash

Answer (score 1):

Multiple tables of identical structure almost never makes sense, you should fix the design if possible.

You can use `INFORMATION_SCHEMA` to get counts, or to list out tables individually (which you could then concat with your sql statement):

```
 SELECT SUM(table_rows) 
 FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES 
 WHERE TABLE_SCHEMA = '{your_db}'
     AND table_name LIKE '%example_table%';
```

If you need exact counts, you should use `CONCAT()` to build a `COUNT()` query, as `INFORMATION_SCHEMA` can be unreliable:

```
SELECT CONCAT('SELECT "',table_name,'" AS table_name, COUNT(*) AS ct FROM ',table_schema,'.',table_name,' UNION') 
FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES 
WHERE TABLE_SCHEMA = '{your_db}' 
  AND table_name LIKE '%example_table%';
```

Comment: hi, thanks for the answer. This structure makes sense because it's a huge database and otherwise the server would crash. This method says I have 2 rows in each table, but this is false. (each table has aprox. 1.200.000 rows)

Comment: thanks for the update! This method gives me a table like: table1 = 100, table2 = 105, etc. And I need this to sum all this numbers